# Django Model Translation with django rest framework not working

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, wagtail, django-modeltranslation

I have successfully implemented models translation and i notice it is working like i can add content in multiple languages from the Django admin but when i implemented in django rest framework, it doesnt work for my expected language, I have successfully sent header for language, translatoin working fine except model translation.

I found this solution: [Model translation in Django Rest Framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57315838/model-translation-in-django-rest-framework) and I found it is good but not getting how to implement this.

This is my views

```
class BlogViewSets(ModelViewSet):
    serializer_class = BlogSerializer
    lookup_field = 'slug'


    def get_queryset(self):
        return BlogPage.objects.all()
```

Can anyone tell me please how can implement this advised solution? [Model translation in Django Rest Framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57315838/model-translation-in-django-rest-framework)

Not getting any way to implement this.

Answer (score 0):

Try that:

```
def get_queryset(self):
    return BlogPage.objects.filter(id__isnull=False)
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).